# DHTMLX Grid filter initialize delay after reset

Tags: javascript, grid, dhtmlx

Strange one, not sure if other code in my application is causing this issue, but here goes.

When I fill a grid with data for the first time, it allows me to use the filters straight away. When I click on my reset button (with text in the filters) to clear the grid and prepare it for the next load, the filters do not work straight away, it seems I have to wait about 5 seconds before the filters will adjust the data. Here's my code, bear in mind, this code runs for both reset button and a search button, meaning that in some scenarios it may run twice before the grid being filled with new data.

Reset Code (called in service):

```
clearAll: function (ref) {
        var gridObj = dhtmlxObjectArray[ref];
        if(gridObj){
            gridObj.clearAll();
            if (gridObj.hdr.rows[1].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0]) {
                gridObj.hdr.rows[1].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked = 0;
            }
            $rootScope.$broadcast("cvsGridService_toggleExport_" + ref, true);
            for (var i = 0; i < gridObj.getColumnsNum(); i++) {
                if (gridObj.getFilterElement(i) != null) {
                    var filterObj = gridObj.getFilterElement(i);
                    filterObj.value = "";
                }
            }
            $scope.$evalAsync();
        }
        $rootScope.$broadcast("cvsGridService_updateGridCount_" + ref);
        $rootScope.$broadcast("cvsGridService_updateFilteredCount_" + ref, 0);
    }
```

The for loop is where the filters get set to blank. So I wonder if it has anything to so with that? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you aren't clearing the filters properly? This is how I do it and it works fine:

```
for (var i=0; i<grid.filters.length; i++){
    grid.filters[i][0].value="";
    grid.filters[i][0].old_value="";
}
grid.filterByAll();
```